# Jhipster - generate a CRUD front end for a parent entity and its children/relationships on one page?

Tags: jhipster

The use case I am thinking of is where you a parent entity "X" that has one or many child entities "Y" and "Y" has a "many to one" relationship to an entity "Z".
I suppose a common example of this would be "An order contains one or more orderItems and each orderItem has a product". This isnt the use case, but the relationships are similar.

Is it possible with j-hipster or blueprints to generate a front end page that lets you create a full parent "X" and its children all on the same page/for?

Comment: Not supported .

Answer (score 0):

This project [generator-jhipster-x](https://github.com/trifonnt/generator-jhipster-x) already has the back-end functionality to manage Parent-Child relationships. Front-end functionality is still work in progress.